# Why is req.geo empty in NextJS on Vercel?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vercel

Why is req.geo an empty object `{}` in my NextJS application, running on Vercel?

`src/app/api/helloWorld`

contains

```
    export async function GET(
    req: NextRequest,
) {
    const searchParams = req.nextUrl.searchParams
    const query = searchParams.get('query');

    console.log("Geo: ", req.geo)

    return Response.json({message: `GET HelloWorld with Search Params: ${searchParams}`})
}
```

Which looking at this page should return me a geo object that at the very least has city?

https://vercel.com/changelog/ip-geolocation-now-available-for-all-plans

I have tried CURL from command line, postman and via a web browser incase that has an impact, but seemingly not. I'm on the hobby plan which it appears is now supported.